# Golang testing programs that involves time

Tags: testing, go, timer

There is an object that relies on timing to function correctly. Unfortunately the timing duration itself is too long to realistically test it in real time and shortening the duration defeats the purpose of the testing due to the nature of the object.

What is the best way to test such an object? Ideally, there would be some virtual clock that runs arbitrarily fast that can be used.

```
type Obj struct{}
func (o Obj) TimeCriticalFunc(d time.Duration) bool {
    //do stuff
    //possibly calling multiple times time.Now() or other real time related functions
}

func TestTimeCriticalFunc(t *testing.T) {
    if !Obj{}.TimeCriticalFunc(10 * 24 * time.Hour) {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an explicit parameter which represent wall time. During test you can fast-forward this wall time. Take a look at how package net/http/cookiejar does it.

Comment: This approach requires modifying the function itself though, which I am kinda reluctant to do. Also brings up the problem of if I were to be testing something involving a function that I do not have code of, I would be helpless

Comment: May be that these kind of objects should always have an explicit parameter representing time. Might do that in the end but I do consider that as a final resort

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was actually answered in Andrew Gerrand's [Testing Techniques talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndmB0bj7eyw). In your code do

```
var (
    timeNow   = time.Now
    timeAfter = time.After
)

// ...

type Obj struct{}
func (o Obj) TimeCriticalFunc(d time.Duration) bool {
    // Call timeAfter and timeNow.
}
```

And in your tests do

```
func TestTimeCriticalFunc(t *testing.T) {
    timeNow = func() time.Time {
        return myTime // Some time that you need
    }
    // "Redefine" timeAfter etc.
    if !Obj{}.TimeCriticalFunc(10 * 24 * time.Hour) {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the anonymous function / closure that the test function sets to the `timeNow` variable (of function time) may keep track of how many times it was called, and it may return different values based on # of call. E.g. `timeNow` may first return `00:00`, on next call it may return `00:01` etc. See this example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ac7PcaTJ_Z).